# Force an iteration of a loop

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

In my "native" programming language (RPG), I can write a loop and just leave the loop or force an iteration. It is kind of like a GOTO.

```
dow (x < 999);
  read file;
  if (%eof);
    leave; // Leave the loop
  endif;
  if (field <> fileField);
    iter; // Iterate to the next record
  endif;
enddo;
```

My question is if there is a similar option is C#. In my case, I am working with a foreach loop.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
continue; // Goto the next iteration
break; // Exit the loop
```

Comment: +1 Clear and concise; exactly what I like to see in an answer.

Comment: That is why I marked it as the answer. It can't get any clearer than that.

Answer (score 5):

[Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4(VS.80).aspx) will exit the loop.
[Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1(VS.80).aspx) will jump to the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1(VS.71).aspx) keyword

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
  {
     if (i < 9) 
        continue;
     Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
```

the output of this is :

```
9
10
```